# Кросс-доменный Ajax-запрос CORS

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, iis, cors

Сервис, на который отправляется запрос $.ajax() - WebApi на .Net Framework версии 4, IIS7. Есть http и https версия.
В  web.config добавил:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

Запрос на http уходит без проблем. При попытке отправить запрос на https ошибка и сообщение в браузере:

```
XMLHttpRequest для https://10.35.25.75:8989/api/findjob требует Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
```

Запрос отправляется из приложения ASP.Net MVC 4:

```
    $.ajax({
                url: 'https://10.35.25.75:8989/api/findjob',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                processData: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: dat,
                success: function (response) {
                    //код обработки ответа
                },
                error: function (response) {
                   //код обработки ошибки            
                }
    });
```

В ошибке статус 0.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) для CORS нужно добавить параметр xhrFields  в ajax запрос.

Актуально для  jQuery 1.5.1+

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://10.35.25.75:8989/api/findjob',

  //Важная часть
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },

  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  processData: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: dat,
  success: function(response) {
    //код обработки ответа
  },
  error: function(response) {
    //код обработки ошибки            
  }
});
```

Comment: Добавление этого параметра не дало результата. Запрос обрывается и выдается сообщение "требует Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)."